# QSqlQuery fails to get SQL Server stored procedure output value

Tags: c++, sql-server, stored-procedures, qt5

I am converting web server code written in VB.NET to Qt 5.15.12. The server accesses a Microsoft SQL Server 2012 database. I have several stored procedures that take an output parameter. The output parameter works as expected with VB.net. One stored procedure is giving me issues in Qt. The stored procedure checks if a record exists in a table. If not, it adds it. If so, it updates it. The stored procedure initially returned `@@ROWCOUNT` but I could not figure out how to get Qt to give me the stored procedure return value so I added an output parameter. The stored procedure essentially looks like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AddUpdateRecord
    @Param1 NChar(12), 
    @Param2 NVarChar(80),
    @RetVal Int Output
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SET @RetVal = 0
    SELECT Column1 FROM MyTable WHERE Column1=@Param1

    IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0
    BEGIN
        UPDATE MyTable SET Column2=@Param2 WHERE Column1=@Param1
        SET @RetVal = @@ROWCOUNT
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO MyTable (Column1, Column2) VALUES (@Param1, @Param2)
        SET @RetVal = @@ROWCOUNT
    END
END
```

The Qt code that calls the stored procedure looks like this:

```
    QSqlQuery   qry(dbObject);
    qry.prepare("execute AddUpdateRecord ?, ?, ?);
    qry.bindValue(0, "012345678912");
    qry.bindValue(1, "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP");
    qry.bindValue(2, QVariant(int(-1)), QSql::Out);
    if (  qry.exec() && (qry.boundValue(2).toInt() > 0) )
    {
        return(true);
    }
    return(false);
```

If I call the stored procedure with a key that does NOT exist, I successfully get the output value. If I call it with a key that DOES exist, the bound value does not change from -1. Am I doing something wrong that is preventing Qt from getting the output value or is this a bug in Qt?

Comment: What do you mean by "a key that does NOT exist" are you referring to `@Param1`? What happens when you run the SP in SSMS?

Comment: `Column1` is primary key. `@Param1` is used to look up the record in the database. When the procedure is run by the VB.NET code, the VB code can get the output parameter whether or not the record exists. When run in SSMS, the output parameter is reported successfully. It is only when run from Qt that the output value does not get bound when the `UPDATE` path is taken. From Qt the output parameter is successfully bound when the `INSERT` path is taken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bare SELECT in the body of the stored procedure sends a resultset to the client.

```
SELECT Column1 FROM MyTable WHERE Column1=@Param1
```

The output parameter is sent after the resultset in the TDS response, and in many client libraries you must consume the resultset before checking the output parameters. You can avoid this and improve this procedure by removing a race condition like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AddUpdateRecord
    @Param1 NChar(12), 
    @Param2 NVarChar(80),
    @RetVal Int Output
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SET @RetVal = 0
    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM MyTable  with (updlock,holdlock) WHERE Column1=@Param1) 
    BEGIN
        UPDATE MyTable SET Column2=@Param2 WHERE Column1=@Param1
        SET @RetVal = @@ROWCOUNT
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO MyTable (Column1, Column2) VALUES (@Param1, @Param2)
        SET @RetVal = @@ROWCOUNT
    END
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END
```

Comment: Your solution works and thanks for the suggestion about avoiding a race condition.  Also,  based on your comment about the result sets, I first tried consuming the results to see if the output parameter would get set and it did. That is very helpful information.